# Visual Basic form property array don't get stored

Tags: arrays, forms, properties, basic

here's my issue:
I made an UserControl containing a ListView called "lstMain".
I have a property inside my controller:

```
Public ReadOnly Property DataRowBoundColumns() As System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection
    Get
        Return Me.lstMain.Columns
    End Get
End Property
```

In the designer I can edit such property BUT when I compile the value gets deleted.
This doesn't happen for the other properties, which are a String, an Integer and other objects (not arrays).
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the data you provide through the collection editor in design mode, do not get serialized.Assuming that your custom control is called "MyCompositeControl" you should write something like the following.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class MyCompositeControl

<DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
Public ReadOnly Property DataRowBoundColumns() As System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ColumnHeaderCollection
    Get
        Return Me.lstMain.Columns
    End Get
End Property

End Class
```